# ModelBinding - Trigger gridview selectmethod with no parameter with the button click event

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page with two ascx controls. The first ascx control contains the textbox and dropdown to allow the user to select the filter parameter. The 2nd control has a gridview to display the query results. The cs file has the gridview select method to call the get data. I notice that upon initial load, the gridview select method gets called. If any of the filter controls is selected, the gridview select method is also called.

Here is the problem, after the initial load, if I click on the search button with no selected filter parameter, the gridview select method does not get called. There is no direct call to the gridview select method. It is specified in the gridview markup language as follow.

I am using modelbinding in my gridview and have the selectmethod declared in my markup aspx file.

My question, how can I get the gridview select method to get call when I click on the button with no selected filtered parameter. Yes, I would like it to do another fetch even if the user makes no selection.

Thanks for any help.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCases" runat="server"
                ItemType="OFAC.FOIA.BusinessEntities.NHObjects.VW_INBOX" 
                DataKeyNames="FOIA_Number"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                SelectMethod="gvCases_GetData"
                OnPreRender="gvCases_PreRender"
                Width="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to know the real answer to this question, but what I ended up doing was to add a HiddenField on the page that the SelectMethod pulled in with a Control Value Provider and then just change the value whenever I wanted to force a refresh. In my case I used a GUID so I wouldn't have to pull back the value, convert it and increment it.

```
protected void ForceGridViewRefresh()
{
    ForceRefresh.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();           
}
```

On my select method:

```
public IEnumerable<TestViewModel> GetData([Control("ForceRefresh")] Guid? forceRefresh)
{
    ...
}
```

So far, this seems to be "working".

Answer (score 0):

you can use GridID.DataBind() and it would immediately call the GridID_GetData() method.

Comment: Works, but like @NFrank said, I'd really like to know the real answer.  This is hackey.

Comment: @D.Dubya Works well for me, too. Why is this hacky? Is this actually discouraged by Microsoft?